# Assigning controller to a form template with $routeProvider in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-controller

I'm building my first angular app, starting with a simple login form. I load the form from a partial, however when I try submitting the form, nothing is logged to the console, i.e. I assume my `authenticate()` method is not called. I have the following definition for my `app.js`:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('spForums',[])
.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider',function($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/login', {
        templateUrl: 'static/partials/login.html',
        controller: loginController,
        controllerAs: 'login'
    });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}])
```

And here's the controller, defined in a separate `controller.js`:

```
'use strict';

function loginController() {
    this.email = '';
    this.password = '';

    this.authenticate = function () {
        console.log(this.email);
        console.log(this.password);
    };
};
```

Here's the partial, `login.html`:

```
<form class="form-signin" novalidate ng-submit="login.authenticate()">
  <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
  <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
  <input type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus ng-model="login.email">
  <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
  <input type="password"  ng-model="login.password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
    </label>
  </div>
  <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Sign-in">
</form>
```

And here's the relevant part of `index.html`, or in my case, `forum.html` that includes the partial:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="spForums">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/lib/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/lib/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container" id="forumcontainer" ng-view>
    </div> <!-- /container -->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/controller.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'd like to end this by saying I'm new to Angular-JS. As in I just saw a bunch of tutorials and this is my first app. Please tell me where I'm wrong.

EDIT:- I'm using Angular-JS version 1.0.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include [`ngRoute`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute) module into your application, it's not shipped by default:

```
<head>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <script src="/static/js/lib/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/lib/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/lib/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Note, that you also need to define `base` href tag, since you are using HTML5 mode.

Then define module with necessary dependencies:

```
angular.module('spForums', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource'])
```

Comment: The version of AngularJS I am using, does not have a separate angular-route.min.js module: https://code.angularjs.org/1.0.7/ I'll add this detail to the original question.

Comment: Also make sure you add `base` tag, see my question, it's also necessary.

Comment: when I submit the form, the details are not logged, i.e `authenticate()` is not called. However, if I do include the dependencies, as with `angular.module('spForums', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource'])` I get a module not found for ngRoute. I Included the `base`.

Comment: If I use version 1.3.14 from Google's CDN, it works the way you described. Wonder why the original was causing problems though.

Comment: I guess because of missing base tag? Here is working demo with 1.0.7: http://plnkr.co/edit/KhrYlChzooB6vYSoDhiB?p=preview